# Generating an interval based on max and min value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I've been working on a script in JavaScript to draw graphic charts and curves based on various type of data on different measures on each category like g, kg, tons for weight or C° or F for temperature etc. and I left the choice of scaling for the user to enter manually the interval which they want to cover, and this part is done.

Now I want to add an option for auto scaling and generate an optimal interval based on min and max values and by optimal I mean a good reading numbers for intervals.
the data varies depending on categories and here all the cases of it:

```
    {min=0, max=45 } => [0,100]  // min= 0 so begin = 0 and 45 is 2 digits so end = 100
    {min=0, max=123 } => [0,200] // begin = 0 , 123 is 3 digits end= 200 
    {min=-45, max=201 } => [-100,300] 
    {min=-1, max=1 } => [-1,1]  
    {min=0.01, max=0.06 } => [0,0.1]
    {min=-0.009, max=-0.004 } => [-0.01,0]
    {min=-0.8, max=0.9 } => [-1,1]
    {min=-335, max=-12 } => [-400,0] 
         ... and so on
```

so I started by the idea of getting numbers of digits using

```
    // if min != 0 && max>=min && max!=0
    // rounding 
    begin=Math.floor(min);
    end=Math.ceil(max);
    // then if end is positive
    // getting the endvalue meaning getting the 10 exponent 
   threshold = Math.pow(10,Math.floor(Math.log10(end)));
    // loop while
       while( end % threshold !=0) end++;
    // else do the rest the same and care for negative values
```

this way it works but not in all cases if anyone want to improve be my guest  thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "good reading numbers for intervals"?

Comment: Is there a question about that code not working? Can you be more specific about *"...not in all cases"*?

Comment: You write *"45 is 2 digits so end = 100"*: why not *"45 is 2 digits so end = 50"*?

Comment: What do you expect for `{min: 0.0194, max: 0.0221}`? Are you sure you want `[0, 1]` for that, making the graph look like a flat line? Shouldn't you want `[0.01, 0.03]`?

Comment: I forget to add the case of small numbers, in fact in case of  {min: 0.0194, max: 0.0221}  the ideal will be  [0,0.1] or [0,0.05] for sure otherwise it will represent a flat line @trincot

Comment: After your comment and edit to the question, I am lost as to which logic you apply. It seems quite arbitrary. Why in the above comment you set the upper limit to 0.05 and not 0.03? What is the logic? It certainly is not logic that shows in your code...

Comment: @ITgoldman by good numbers i mean optimal value for reading that are rounded based on multiples of power of 10 or 5 (0,10,20,..)  or  (0.01, 0.02, 0.03) For example the basic is to get (max-min)/scale to get the scale step width then round up the max and min value to get the best interval to draw the chart , but sometimes if you have max = 101 the best end is 150 or 200 and also depend on min

Comment: Now I understand. You want to translate the scale proportionally to the nearest power of 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks:

- `Math.log10(0)` is -Infinity, so take care when `end` is 0.
- When the threshold for the min-value is different from the one for the max-value, I assume you want to apply the greatest of those two.
- The `while` loop is not efficient. Instead, you can divide the number by the threshold, and ceil that, and then multiply again.

Here is the adjusted code. I added your test cases. For the first one it reports a difference, but I think the logic should be that 45 is rounding up to 50, not 100:

```js
function getThreshold(n) {
    return n && Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(n))));
}

function getRange({min, max}) {
    min = Math.floor(min);
    max = Math.ceil(max);
    let threshold = Math.max(getThreshold(min), getThreshold(max));
    min = min && Math.round(Math.floor(min / threshold) * threshold);
    max = max && Math.round(Math.ceil(max / threshold) * threshold);
    return [min, max];
}

let tests = [
    [{min:0, max:45 }, [0,100]],
    [{min:0, max:123 }, [0,200]], 
    [{min:-45, max:201 }, [-100,300]],
    [{min:-1, max:1 }, [-1,1]],  
    [{min:0.01, max:0.6 }, [0,1]],
    [{min:-0.8, max:0.9 }, [-1,1]],
    [{min:-335, max:-12 }, [-400,0]],
];
for (let [input, expected] of tests) {
    let result = getRange(input);
    if (JSON.stringify(result) !== JSON.stringify(expected)) {
        console.log("got", ...result, "expected", ...expected);
    }
}
console.log("all done");
```

As discussed in comments, for small ranges (like [0.00193, 0.00221]), it would be better to not require that the output consists of *integers*, but could be something like [0.001, 0.003].

In that case you can use this:

```js
function getThresholdPower(n) {
    return n && Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(n)));
}

function getRange({min, max}) {
    let thresholdPower = Math.max(getThresholdPower(min), getThresholdPower(max));
    let threshold = 10 ** Math.abs(thresholdPower);
    // Deal with negative powers differently 
    // to avoid floating point precision issues
    if (thresholdPower < 0) {
        min = min && Math.floor(min * threshold) / threshold;
        max = max && Math.ceil(max * threshold) / threshold;
    } else {
        min = min && Math.floor(min / threshold) * threshold;
        max = max && Math.ceil(max / threshold) * threshold;
    }
    return [min, max];
}

let tests = [
    [{min:0, max:45 }, [0,100]],
    [{min:0, max:123 }, [0,200]], 
    [{min:-45, max:201 }, [-100,300]],
    [{min:-1, max:1 }, [-1,1]],  
    [{min:0.01, max:0.6 }, [0,1]],
    [{min:-0.8, max:0.9 }, [-1,1]],
    [{min:-335, max:-12 }, [-400,0]],
];
for (let [input, expected] of tests) {
    let result = getRange(input);
    if (JSON.stringify(result) !== JSON.stringify(expected)) {
        console.log("got", ...result, "expected", ...expected);
    }
}
console.log("all done");
```

Obviously, this snippet reports more deviations from what was mentioned as expected output.

Comment: good idea for replacing the loop , but i think your answer does not cover all tests for example {min: -9, max: 9} will output [-9,9] instead of [-10,10]

Comment: Why is [-9, 9] not OK? It fits with the logic that you have implemented, i.e. looking for the *first* multiple of the threshold, which is 1 in this case, and so the first multiple that encompasses the initial range, is the range itself. If this is not what you want, can you edit your question and explain the logic you want in an unambiguous formula?

Comment: Yeah i know its a bit confusing but your solution work perfectly for most cases , the -9 , 9 example is just a specific case for a specific chart that because values are in integers between -10 and 10 so I will treat this separately thanks for your answer @trincot

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not exactly like you wanted, but this normalizes to a scale that is a power of 10.

```js
function normalize_to_10_power(value, is_down) {
    if (is_down) {
        if (value > 0) {
            return Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(value)))
        }
        if (value < 0) {
            return -Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(-value)))
        }
    } else {
        if (value > 0) {
            return Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(value)))
        }
        if (value < 0) {
            return -Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(-value)))
        }
    }
    return 0
}

function normalize_range(min, max) {
    return [
        normalize_to_10_power(min, true),
        normalize_to_10_power(max)
    ]
}

var tests = [
    [{ min: 0, max: 45 }, [0, 100]],
    [{ min: 0, max: 123 }, [0, 200]],
    [{ min: -45, max: 201 }, [-100, 300]],
    [{ min: -1, max: 1 }, [-1, 1]],
    [{ min: 0.01, max: 0.6 }, [0, 1]],
    [{ min: -0.009, max: -0.004 }, [0, 1]],
    [{ min: -0.8, max: 0.9 }, [-1, 1]],
    [{ min: -335, max: -12 }, [-400, 0]],
];

for (let [input, expected] of tests) {
    var result = normalize_range(input.min, input.max);
    console.log("input: ", input, "result: ", result);
}
```

note that {min=-0.009, max=-0.004 } => [-0.01,0]
should be [-0.01, -0.001] (if we go by this algorithm)